# A complete log of this run can be found in:

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, linux, react-native

```
npm ERR! code ENOTEMPTY
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli
npm ERR! dest /usr/local/lib/node_modules/.expo-cli-dKBr48UN
npm ERR! errno -39
npm ERR! ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.expo-cli-dKBr48UN'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-03-04T10_48_56_967Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  Make sure you have the latest version of nodejs and npm (`node ​​-v`, `npm -v`).
Often, the official repositories of the Linux distribution may not have the latest version of nodejs.  I recommend uninstalling nodejs and npm first and then loading them via nvm.  (After installing nvm, write `nvm install node`, and npm will be installed automatically together with nodejs)